# Evaluate an address

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

This is a really basic question but I can't get it done.

All I want is to be able to input the value of a cell from another workbook. However, the sheet is dynamically determined.

For example, I have my current workbook with A1=January, A2=3 and A3=33. It means I want to get the value of C33 in the sheet January of the workbook also named January.xlsx.

Here is what I currently have:

```
ADDRESS(3;33;1;1;"'N:\[" & A1 & ".xlsx"]" & A1 & "'")
```

It gives me a #REF! error.

And I have no idea how to evaluate the result address after, I tried:

```
INDIRECT('N:\[January.xlsx]January'!C33)
```

... but it also gives me a #REF! error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) [Address](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/address-HP005208983.aspx) Uses Row,Column Number as parameters

```
ADDRESS(row_num,column_num,abs_num,a1,sheet_text)
```

so your ADDRESS Formula will be

```
=ADDRESS(A3,A2,1,1,"N:\["&A1&".xlsx"&"]"&A1)
```

2) [Indirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837103/reference-data-in-closed-excel-sheet) needs the external workbook to be open

If the external workbook is closed then copy the output of the Address as value and add `=`

For e.g.

using the address formula as shown above will give the result

```
'N:\[January.xlsx]January'!$C$33
```

Copy  this value into a new column ,Paste as Value and add `=`

`='N:\[January.xlsx]January'!$C$33`

will get the value from the external workbook

Comment: How can I do it without opening the workbook? The other workbooks are data only and I need to generate a report with those datas, I obviously don't want to open 24 workbooks to get the data from the last 2 years.

Comment: You can paste the address as value and add '=' before the address

Comment: Ya but I want to do that automatically (ie. without any manual intervention). I mean, if I can get the cell A1 from a definedFile.xlsx even if it's close, what is the difference from getting the cell (X,Y) from a file defined by a cell value? Why would it be so different?..

Comment: You'll probably need some VBA Code to do this automatically!

Comment: I know I can do it with VBA, but I don't understand why I can't do it with Excel formulas.

Answer (score 1):

With A1=January, A2=C and A3=33 and with *January.xlsx* open, in A4 enter:

```
="[" & A1 & ".xlsx" & "]" & A1 & "!" & A2 & A3
```

and in A5 enter:

```
=INDIRECT(A4)
```

[image: demo]

**Remember January.xlsx must be open.**

Comment: How can I do it without opening the workbook? The other workbooks are data only and I need to generate a report with those datas, I obviously don't want to open 24 workbooks to get the data from the last 2 years.